# WP_Error message

Tags: errors, fatal-error

`PHP Notice: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to int in /var/www/vhosts/hayhauler.co/httpdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2568, referer: http://hayhauler.co/`

I'm not even sure where to start with this or the right question to ask. I know that it is preventing me from posting some information into a database using this:

```
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare(
  "
    INSERT INTO $wpdb->quotes
    (user_ID,origin,destination,broker_ID,quote_ID,estimatedship)
    VALUES (%d,%s,%s,%d,%s,%s)
  ",
  $user_id,
  $origin,
  $destination,
  $brokerID,
  $brokerID.'-'.genRandomString(),
  $estimatedship
));
```

And this error follows it:

`mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /var/www/vhosts/hayhauler.co/httpdocs/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 789, referer: http://hayhauler.co/`

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the variables you're trying to pass into `wpdb::prepare` is a [`WP_Error`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error) object.  `WP_Error`'s are like exceptions mixed with return codes: some functions in the WordPress API return WP_Error objects to tell you something went wrong (like [`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)).

We'll need to see more of your code to be more specific, but you can test for them with the function [`is_wp_error`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_wp_error).  So, let's say $brokerID was causing the issue:

```
<?php
$brokerID = some_function_that_gets_broker_id();

if(is_wp_error($brokerID))
{
    // do stuff to fix it
}
else
{
    // Your original code goes here.
}
```

Comment: Wow. This form of error checking is a whole new word for me. Thanks. It helped point me in the right direction. Basically, `$estimatedship` didn't have a corresponding column in the table.

I'm just not sure why WP didn't throw a more specific error into the window since I had `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`